# How to use 2 different conditions to filter an array in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

I am trying to create a new array, which will consist of (data value <=20000) from the first column, along with all other corresponding columns.

Mathematically I am doing the following: I am reading data from a text file. I am finding distance to all the points from the last point. Then I will take only those rows with distances less than 20000 and M1 less than 11.5. 
The data looks as follows:

```
# ID M1 M2 M3 M4 R4 M5 R5 x y z
10217 11.467 11.502 13.428 13.599  432.17 13.266  281.06 34972.8 42985.9 14906
7991 11.529 11.559 13.438 13.520  435.23 13.224  272.23 8538.05 33219.8 43375.1
2100 11.526 11.573 13.478 13.490  448.97 13.356  301.27 9371.75 13734.1 43398.6
9467 11.557 11.621 13.481 13.537  449.99 13.367  303.67 33200.3 36008.9 12735.8
```

my code looks the following:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


halo = 'nntest.txt'
ID, m,r,x,y,z= np.loadtxt(halo, usecols=(0,6,7,8,9,10), unpack =True)



# selet the last point
m_mass = m[-1:]
ID_2 = ID[-1:]
r_2 = r[-1:]
x_2 = x[-1:]
y_2 = y[-1:]
z_2 = z[-1:]

#######################################
#Find distance to all points from our targeted point
nearest_neighbors = []

def neighbors(ID_2, cx,cy,cz, ID, m, r, x, y, z):

    dist = np.sqrt((cx-x)**2 + (cy-y)**2 + (cz-z)**2)

    return dist, ID, m, r, x, y, z

for i in range(len(ID_2)):
    hist = neighbors(ID_2[i], m_2[i], r_2[i], x_2[i], y_2[i], z_2[i], ID, m , r, x, y, z)



    #print all the IDs and all other data which are less than 20000 and M less than 11.5  of that targeted value
    print ID[hist[0]<20000] and m[hist[1]<11.5]
```

But I am  having problem with setting the 2 conditions. It returns me this error:

```
File "overlaping_halos_finder.py", line 53, in <module>
    combined = zip(ID[hist[0]<r_2[i] and m[hist[1]>1.e12]])
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

if instead of

```
print ID[hist[0]<20000] and m[hist[1]<11.5]
```

I do only:

```
print ID[hist[0]<20000]
```

I have following sample output:

```
# ID M R X Y Z
6737.0 909913272632.0 103.06 1988.35 15894.6 40649.0
6617.0 997700063823.0 106.28 1523.55 15433.2 40363.2
6723.0 11 109.91 1993.05 15687.5 40557.2
```

But I want to get rid of those first two outputs and only want to print the 3 rd row where M column value <11.5

hope it clarifies a little

Your suggestion to fix this issue will be very helpful

Comment: Can you describe exactly what you are trying to do? `setting the 2 conditions` doesn't explain what you are trying to achieve. Ideally, you can show us an example of 2 small arrays and desired output.

Comment: I am trying to print only those rows for which calculated distance (from the neighbors function) will be less than 20000. At the same time those also have to meet the condition that the value of m column is less than 11.5

Comment: So, to clarify, do you want a *tuple* of 2 arrays as your output, filtered by Boolean arrays `hist[0]<20000` and `hist[1]<11.5` respectively? As far as I can see `ID` and `m` are 2 separate arrays.

Comment: Or maybe you want `ID[(hist[0]<20000) & (hist[1]<11.5)]` ?

Comment: yes, I just want a tuple where those two filters are applied

Comment: I think I need two different conditions separately. first refine only M array <11.5. then calculate dist from function, and then refine again for dist<2000 for ID, this way I can get those refinements together

Comment: What about `print (ID[hist[0]<20000], m[hist[1]<11.5])` ? This is a tuple of arrays, one Boolean array used to index `ID`. Another Boolean array used to index `m`.

Comment: I think that solves the problem. Thanks very much for your time

Comment: No problem, I wrote up the answer for reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need logical `and`. To print a `tuple` of arrays, simply print a comma-separated sequence of arrays:

```
print ID[hist[0]<20000], m[hist[1]<11.5]
```

`ID` will be indexed by the Boolean array `hist[0]<20000`, while `m` will be indexed by the Boolean array `hist[1]<11.5`.

If you need to assign to variables, you can use sequence unpacking:

```
res1, res2 = ID[hist[0]<20000], m[hist[1]<11.5]
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand your code, but from the title I advise you to define a function that given one point, returns true if that point should be filtered. Then you can do:

```
def filter_point(point):
    # Conditions over a single point
    # You can read from global variables here, or create a partial function
    # to access external data

    return condition1(point) and condition2(point)

result = filter(filter_point, list_of_points)
```